# Euler project in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

My background is in python programming, and I'm interested in learning assembly to see whats "under the hood".  I've solved the first forty odd euler problems in python, and I figured they would be a good exercise to develop my assembly skills. I haven't made it past problem 1 (what is the sum of all the factors of 3 and 5 below 1000?).

Here's what I've got so far. Note that this is incomplete and is only the first part of the program, and should only find the factors of three below 1000

```
.data
sum:        .float 0.0
currentnum: .float 1000.0
num1:       .float 3.0
num2:       .float 5.0
zero:       .float 0.0
one:        .float 1.0

.text
main:
lw    $t0  currentnum       # move all variables into temporary registers t0 - t5
lw    $t1  num1
lw    $t2  num2
lw    $t3  zero
lw    $t4  one
lw    $t5  sum       

factors_of_3:                # finds all factors of 3, adds to sum
sub    $t0, $t0 $t4          #begin by subtracting 1 from currentnum, 1st val of currentnum = 999
beqz   $t0, end              # escape loop if currentnum == 0
div    $t0, $t1              # divides the current number by 3, places answer in lo    remainder in hi
mfhi   $t6                   # moves the remainder to temporary register t6             
bne    $t6, $t3 factors_of_3  # if the remainder =/= 0, jump to factors_of_3
add    $t5, $t5, $t0          #otherwise, sum = sum + currentnum
j factors_of_3
    syscall 
end:
```

For some reason, every time I run this, the register that sum is in remains at 0, and all the other register (the ones I defined, t0-t5) are displaying nonsensically large hex numbers.  Just for reference, running the line `sum(x for x in range (1000) if (x % 3 ==0))` in the python shell gives 166833, which should be the correct answer.

Comment: You should be using integer constants, not floats.

Comment: I thought about this, but integers don't work for the way I'm solving it.  What I'm doing is starting a loop with `currentnum = 1000`, doing `currentnum = currentnum-1` at the beginning of every loop, then    `if currentnum % 3 == 0, sum = sum + currentnum`.  I can't do that with integers.  Of course, instead of counting down from 1000 and checking whether each number is evenly divisible by 3, I could count up from n=1 doing 3*n and stopping the loop when 3*n >= 1000.

Comment: Sure you can do that with integers. You don't have any floating point operations in there, do you? `%` is specifically integer division with remainder.

Comment: Oh, is it?  Never knew that... I assume the `div` command used here operates in the same way...  I'll tweak everything and run it and tell you all what happens.    EDIT:  I changed all the datatypes to `.word` and it ran perfectly! thanks!  Just for the sake of learning, could anyone explain to me why floating point division did not produce the proper remainder?  (my uneducated guess: no remainder)

Comment: The registers and the instructions were integer but you loaded a floating point value. For example, the bit pattern that means `1000.0` as float, means something different as an integer, namely `1148846080`. Your code operated on wrong data with integer instructions. To use floats, you need to use floating point registers and floating point instructions (or emulate those using integer instructions).